# Chrome browser Issue in one server only

Tags: google-chrome, browser, load-balancing

I have problem related to loading of a website in only chrome browser. The same website when deployed to other server has got no issues and also it is running fine on IE/firefox without any issues. Actually we deploy our website in different environments i.e different servers. But on one server this issue is happening. I removed "Enable phishing and malware protection" and "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" from chrome browser but still the issue persist. This is the first time I am seeing this kind of issue. As if it would have been issue with browser compatibility of chrome then it should have been on both the servers but issue is only on one server and that too only for chrome. Please guide me on this as I am stuck. I am not getting any clue about this.
Thanks,
Manish

Comment: I had nailed down the issue...this issue happens when I try to connect to the server through load balancer but instead if i directly access the server without going through load balancer it works fine...also if i connect to the server through load balancer with a fiddler2 session started it works fine...so something related to load balancer and chrome that i am not getting...any help...

Comment: The issue was related to F5 server 2.0.1.3 build which has issues with sub domain character length more than 6 in the next build it was solved... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to F5 server 2.0.1.3 build which has issues with sub domain character length more than 6 in the next build it was solved... thanks